# vertically align pgfplots to baseline by y label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically align some `pgfplots` generated plots by their respective y axis label. Because I want some text (or math symbols) along with that, I'm trying to use the TikZ option `baseline=(node.position)`, but somehow, I can't access the `ylabel` node. Here's a mockup example, with plots taken from the [pgfplots gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ylabel.center)]
  \begin{axis}[
      height=5cm,
      xlabel=Cost,
      ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (2,-2.8559703)
      (3,-3.5301677)
      (4,-4.3050655)
      (5,-5.1413136)
      (6,-6.0322865)
      (7,-6.9675052)
      (8,-7.9377747)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ylabel.center)]
  \begin{axis}[
      height=4cm,
      xmin=-3,   xmax=3,
      ymin=-3,   ymax=3,
      extra x ticks={-1,1},
      extra y ticks={-2,2},
      extra tick style={grid=major},
      xlabel=x,
      ylabel=y,
    ]
    \draw[red] \pgfextra{
      \pgfpathellipse{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{1}{0}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0}{2}}
    };
    \draw[blue] \pgfextra{
      \pgfpathellipse{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{1}{1}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0}{2}}
    };
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*] coordinates { (0,0) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ylabels are not given the name `ylabel` by default, but you can add that by saying `ylabel style={name=ylabel}` in the `axis` options.

Alternatively, you could say `[baseline=(current axis.east)]` and not add the `ylabel style`, which gives the same output (in this case at least).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ylabel.center)]
  \begin{axis}[
      height=5cm,
      xlabel=Cost,
      ylabel=Error,
      ylabel style={name=ylabel}]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (2,-2.8559703)
      (3,-3.5301677)
      (4,-4.3050655)
      (5,-5.1413136)
      (6,-6.0322865)
      (7,-6.9675052)
      (8,-7.9377747)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ylabel.center)]
  \begin{axis}[
      height=4cm,
      xmin=-3,   xmax=3,
      ymin=-3,   ymax=3,
      extra x ticks={-1,1},
      extra y ticks={-2,2},
      extra tick style={grid=major},
      xlabel=x,
      ylabel=y,
      ylabel style={name=ylabel}
    ]
    \draw[red] \pgfextra{
      \pgfpathellipse{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{1}{0}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0}{2}}
    };
    \draw[blue] \pgfextra{
      \pgfpathellipse{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{1}{1}}
             {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0}{2}}
    };
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*] coordinates { (0,0) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```